# JUnit weaving wrong Spring AOP Bean

Tags: java, spring, junit, aop

I've run into a strange problem that I am having difficulty tracking down.  I have an class (ServiceErrorInterceptor) defined as an `@Aspect` which is instantiated via XML configuration as a singleton bean.  The XML configuration allows me to inject its dependent beans.

In my normal workflow, everything works fine.  The aspect class is properly instantiated, and whenever the advice is called, the injected beans are as I would expect.

However, when I run my JUnit test, all my injected beans are null.  This leads me to the conclusion that the advice is called from a different bean - not the same singleton bean that was instantiated by Spring.  To further validate my hypothesis, I put a breakpoint on a setter which is called during the instantiation, and see that the bean id is not the same as the bean id if I put a breakpoint in my advice.

Is there some special configuration I must enable in my JUnit class to rectify this?  My test class is already annotate with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { 
        "classpath:spring/applicationContext-base.xml", 
        "classpath:spring/applicationContext-calculateServices.xml", 
        "classpath:spring/applicationContext-dom.xml"})
public class LendingSimulationServiceImplTest {
...
...
}
```

I've looked through the logs (I enabled spring trace logs), but don't see anything that stands out.  And posting the entire log here would likely be overkill.  If there is value in a specific part of the log please let me know and I will post it.

I'm able to post my code for the aspect, my junit and my config if that is helpful.

application-context.xml snippet:

```
<!-- SPRING ASPECT BEAN.  POINTCUT DEFINED IN BEAN WITH ANNOTATION -->
<bean id="serviceErrorInterceptor" class="com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.error.ServiceErrorInterceptor" scope="singleton">
    <property name="errorMessageProvider" ref="resourceBundleProviderImpl"/>
    <property name="defaultLocale">
        <util:constant static-field="java.util.Locale.ENGLISH" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

My bean is implemented as:

```
@Aspect
public class ServiceErrorInterceptor {

    /**
     * Logger
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceErrorInterceptor.class);

    /**
     * SOAP Header data
     */
    @Autowired
    private SOAPHeaderData soapHeaderData;

    public ServiceErrorInterceptor(){
        int x = 0;
        x=x+1;

    }

    /**
     * Exception Interceptor. 
     * @param ex
     */
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.process.CalculatorProcess.calculate (..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void errorInterceptor(Exception ex) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Error Message Interceptor started");
        }

    }
```

The relevant portions of my pom:

```
    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
        spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for AspectJ Annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've done further debugging and putting a breakpoint in the dummy constructor, I get the following results:

- with @Aspect and XML configuration, the constructor is called twice (different bean ids)
- if I remove the @Aspect annotation then it is only called once.
- If leave the @Aspect but remove the XML configuration, then the constructor isn't even called.
- If I use an @Component annotation in combination with @Aspect (but without any XML configuration), then the bean is constructed twice.
- Oddly enough, however, with both the @Component and @Aspect annotations *AND* the XML configuration, the constructor is still only called twice.

So then why would having both the XML configuration and the @Aspect annotation cause the constructor to be called twice with two different bean ids?

I have further validated that if I move the entire AOP definition into the XML configuration (removing the @Aspect and @Pointcut annotations) then the bean is only constructed once.

**END EDIT**

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of discussion with the folks over at the SpringSource STS forum (see [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?125470-How-to-enable-AspectJ-nature-in-a-Spring-project-with-annotated-and-aj-aspects)), it turns out that the issue is related to the AJDT configuration.  At the moment, AJ is weaving in the aspect, and Spring is locating the aspect on the Classpath, so they are both being executed.

Unfortunately, the AJ maven plugin is missing a configuration parameter to allow for exclusion of weaving; the current configuration excludes both LTW and CTW.

So, the workaround at the moment is to add `-xmlConfigured` to the AJ compiler flags and then specify an aop.xml file in aop.xml management which only lists the AJ aspects that you want to include in the project.

> To get this to work, add '-xmlConfigured' to the Project Properties
>   'Non-standard compiler options' and then in AspectJBuild>'aop.xml
>   management' point it at a simple aop.xml file:
>
> ```
> <aspectj> 
>     <aspects> 
>        <aspect name="com.fooMyNewNoneSpringAspect"/>
>     </aspects> 
> </aspectj>
> ```

Thanks to Andy Clement at the STS forum for this discovery and workaround.  He will be raising JIRA issues to further address this shortcoming in the maven plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Does your aspect by any chance have any of the autodetect annotations (@Component, @Service) etc, apart from @Aspect - if it does, that could be one reason why a different bean seems to be present along with the one defined in your configuration.

Also, just scan through all your configuration to make sure that you are not declaring this bean elsewhere.

There is nothing special that needs to be done at the Junit level that I am aware of.

Comment: No.  The only annotation is @Aspect.  Additionally, if there was an additional bean, it would have shown up in the Spring logs as a duplicate bean definition.  There was nothing in the logs.  I just realized that I am using AspectJ as well for other weaving other aspects into other classes, but I don't see how or why that would affect anything.

Comment: can you confirm that you are using @Aspect annotations with Spring AOP and not compile time or load time weaving using AspectJ, if it is compile time or load time weaving, then the way to inject dependencies into an aspect is a little different: using aspectOf factory method - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: I am using @Aspect annotations with Spring AOP.  I addded some AspectJ weaving for some other aspects, but have since removed them from the pom and the package.  Removal of AJ has made no difference.  I have edited my question with additional information.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to persist along the same lines once more @Eric, just want to be very sure - are you using Eclipse with Ajbuilder(using AJDT) enabled for your project by any chance, even that would tend to do compile team weaving of your code with a different instance of the aspect. I have tried a lot of permutations but have not been able to replicate your behavior at all with normal Spring AOP - check project 3 here - git://github.com/bijukunjummen/AOP-Samples.git

Comment: I appreciate the the peristence actually.  Indeed, I am using STS and have the AspectJ nature enabled on the project.  I will try to disable the AJ nature on Monday when I get back to the office and see if it makes a difference.  If so, then does this mean I cannot enable AJ nature on a project which uses AspectJ annotated aspects in a Spring AOP project?

Comment: I removed the AspectJ nature from the project and the unit tests runs properly with my `@Aspect` annotation enabled.  So this confirms your suspicion.  Thank you so much.  Now, the $1million dollar question is if there is a way to combine both AspectJ annotations, .aj aspects and AspectJ nature within a Spring project?  It would appear not.  Or something is missing in my configuration.  Is there something specific / special I must do to configure AJ Nature/Spring project to support both AJ and annotated AJ Aspects for Spring?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way you might find yourself in the same situation: you used the **new** operator rather than letting Spring **inject** your service.

Remember, we're not in AspectJ compile time weaving here. Nope, we're using Spring AOP proxies, so Spring must instantiate the object and dress it with proxies. If you were silly, like myself, and created a new service inside your tests, you won't get any AOP.

All the more reason to do compile time weaving with AspectJ and skip over all of the drawbacks of Spring AOP such as runtime weaving startup delay, inability to weave non-public and non-final classes.