# spring aspect being applied outside of app context (in stubbed out unit test)

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, aop

Here's a weird one. I've got a few tests failing because an aspect is being applied, so an autowired service is null, bad things ensue. The issue is that I can't understand *how* the aspect is even being applied, since in the test I construct the object under test with new.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TheControllerTest {

    @Spy
    private TheController controller = new TheController();

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    private ConfigService configService;
  ....

@Before
public void setup() {
    controller.setConfigService(configService);
....
    }

@Test
public void testGetAccountsList() throws Exception {
Mockito.when(accountService.getAllAccounts()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(account1,     account2));

    Map<String, Object> result = controller.getAccountsList(request);
...    
}
}
```

I'm obviously omitting plenty of code, but really, I just don't understand how, given how controller is instantiated, it could have had the advice applied.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be if you are running this in Eclipse - in a project with ajbuilder enabled, even if you are explicitly expecting Spring AOP through dynamic proxies, ajbuilder would actually perform compile team weaving, and hence you would see advice enhanced classes even using normal "new". Can you please check this, the fix would be to disable "ajbuilder" - here is one reference - [JUnit weaving wrong Spring AOP Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10129929/204788)

Comment: I don't see any reference to ajbuilder in the properties for this project, but this is a maven project, not being built (exclusively) in eclipse. In the pom.xml for the project, I do see a dependency for the aspectjweaver. Could that be related?

Comment: No, I doubt this could be it, do you have `aspectj-maven-plugin` in your pom.xml by any chance.